# Appending cell value with fixed text AND value of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I wish to append every cell value within a column range in Excel (2013).

For example:-

Cell `BT742` contains *Almond Juice* currently.
Cell `AT742` contains *8mg* currently.

I wish to append cell value `BT742` to be *Almond Juice - 8mg*.

I have got as far as this so far:-

```
=BT742 & " -  "
```

Which is working perfectly as this results in `Almond Juice -`

I'm just struggling on how to extend this formula to add cell value `AT742` on the end of this value.

Please could someone advise of the correct formula syntax to use in this instance? Thanks.

Comment: Also, `BT742` and `AT742` are cells, not a columns :)

Comment: That was just one row as an example given in a column.

Comment: Oh sorry Jerry, I see what you mean - My mistake on line 3, I meant cell. Been edited now, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use & again to concatenate, e.g.

`=BT742 & " -  " & AT742`

Comment: Perfect, thanks @barry houdini. Can't believe I didn't try that. Hah. :) Will accept answer when SO allows me to in 9 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Barry's answer is perfectly right. An alternate to this is using the `CONCATENATE()` function:

```
=CONCATENATE(BT742, " - ", AT742)
```

Comment: @DavidZemens Yup. And after multiple concatenates, I find it more tedious to type the `&` symbol than `,`. :)